# How do I best parse a date string in the Python C API?

Tags: python-c-api

Unfortunately there seems to be no `PyDateTime_FromString()` (equivalent to e.g. `PyFloat_FromString()`) in the Python C API. Has anybody figured out what would be the ideal workaround if I have to parse a date string into a `datetime.datetime` type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [`PyDateTime_FromTimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/datetime.html#c.PyDateTime_FromTimestamp) does not suffice, you can just call any Python method like [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) directly:

```
PyObject *datetimeType = (PyObject *) PyDateTimeAPI->DateTimeType;
PyObject *datetime = PyObject_CallMethod(datetimeType, "strptime", "ss",
                                            "11-11-11 11:11:11", //date_string
                                            "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"); //format
```

But keep in mind, that `PyDateTimeAPI->DateTimeType` is not part of the documented API, so it could break eventually any time in the future. I've tested this with Python versions 2.7.9 and 3.4.2 only. Instead you should do the equivalent of `from datetime import datetime` in your C code.

Comment: Thanks `strptime` worked for me. `PyDateTime_FromTimestamp` does not help me on Windows since it is Unix related.

Comment: What does "ss" mean (3rd parameter)?

Comment: I states that `strptime` takes two string parameters.